# HDMI-0 Disconnected When Plugged In Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: multiple-monitors, monitor, xrandr

My external monitor (Classified as HDMI-0) is not turning on or being detected when I plug the HDMI in my computer. I have tried replugging the monitor in as well as restarting my computer.

Here is the `xrandr` output.

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
eDP-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     60.02*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32
```

### Update

```
xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 2
Provider 0: id: 0x1b8 cap: 0x1, Source Output crtcs: 4 outputs: 1 associated providers: 1 name:NVIDIA-0
Provider 1: id: 0x1e1 cap: 0x6, Sink Output, Source Offload crtcs: 3 outputs: 1 associated providers: 1 name:modesetting
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu do you use? Could you provide result of `xrandr --listproviders` and `xorg.conf` content?

Comment: @Serg I am using Ubuntu 21.10.
`xrandr --listproviders` output is :

`Providers: number : 2
Provider 0: id: 0x1b8 cap: 0x1, Source Output crtcs: 4 outputs: 1 associated providers: 1 name:NVIDIA-0
Provider 1: id: 0x1e1 cap: 0x6, Sink Output, Source Offload crtcs: 3 outputs: 1 associated providers: 1 name:modesetting`
`xorg.conf` command wasn't found.

Comment: Sorry, please provide output of `cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf`

Comment: Also you have 2 video cards, could you please provide information about the second card (the first is nVidia)

Comment: And run `xrandr --output HDMI-0 --auto`

Comment: @Serg The 2nd GPU is an Intel iGPU, the Intel UHD 630 I believe.
`cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf` had no output whatsoever.
Same thing with `xrandr --output HDMI-0 --auto`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it through a system update which restarted my computer, I don't know how or why but it worked for me.